# How to export lastest airflow dag and task status in tabular format for specific owners

Tags: airflow, airflow-api

Airflow provides rest API functionality to extracts dag/task status.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Trying-the-API

But wondering if there a way to get latest dag/task status of all dags w.r.t dag owner only without specifying it manually for each dag id.

This will help us for creating a workflow dashboard for business users.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `dag`, `dag_run` and `task_instsnce` tables in airflow metadata database. It's fairly straightforward..